# Associating user data with session key

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have created a session in django1.10 for a user.I want to know how all data generated by my code can be associated with session_key.All these data are stored in mysql tables.So that when many users login simultaneously all data will be associated with the respective users.

Comment: associate data in mysql table with session_key.so that when user logsout along with session key the data is also deleted.

Comment: You can use clear session which is provided by django that removes all expired seesion from db.https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/django-admin/#django-contrib-sessions

Comment: i want to associate all data generated with the session_key..so that data will be different for different users who have logged in simultaneously

Comment: You dont need to deal with session key for this task.When a user does login, just add a unique key to the session and maintain that key in all the records the user adds.Once the user clicks on logout truncate all the tables bases on this unique key in the session.Thus all users will be using same tables and data entered by them will be visible only to them.

Comment: Thanks shadow0359. you understood what i was asking..how do i add a unique key to the session and maintain the key in tables in mysql..i am very new to django..would be great if you could give detailed answer..Thank you

Comment: How does the user login?oauth or username and password?

Comment: cookies will be generated if correct username and password is given..response = requests.post(url, json=authenticationString, headers=headerString)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a user column in all your tables.when the user logs in store a unique value in the session(can be user ID or email).

```
request.session['USER_ID'] = userId(or email)
```

Now,this id will be there in the request and can be accesses through out your project.

When adding a record along with all the data add the userId to the table for the user column.you can access it in your views as request.session.get('USER_ID').Just add this id to all your queries.

Comment: This userid is defined in myviews(function) but i need to use thos userid in logout function.

Comment: logout function also has request.Access it the same way. request.session.get('USER_ID')